# Service worker scope issue

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have loaded this code in the index.html of my mobile website:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/theme/website_mobile/sw.js').then(function(reg) {

if(reg.installing) {
  console.log('Service worker installing');
} else if(reg.waiting) {
  console.log('Service worker installed');
} else if(reg.active) {
  console.log('Service worker active');
}

}).catch(function(error) {
// registration failed
console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
});
}
```

In the sw.js, I have added this code :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/theme/website_mobile/js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/css',
        '/theme/website_mobile/js.js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/css.css',
        '/js/614cd8e.js',
        '/css/f1407bb.css',
        '/js/93779bc.js',
        '/js/d228ec7.js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider1.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider2.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider3.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider4.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/logo-website.png',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/picto-menu-close.png',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/picto-close.png',
        '/var/website/storage/images/media/website-medias/website-materials/5163440-1-eng-GB/website-materials_article_list_main_website_enm.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-Light.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-avenir/Fonts/065a6b14-b2cc-446e-9428-271c570df0d9.woff2',
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
    // caches.match() always resolves
    // but in case of success response will have value
    if (response !== undefined) {
      return response;
    } else {
      return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
        // response may be used only once
        // we need to save clone to put one copy in cache
        // and serve second one
        let responseClone = response.clone();

        caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
        });
        return response;
      }).catch(function (e) {
        return caches.match('/');
      });
    }
  }));
});
```

The sw.js is activated, I don't have any errors on the console, but if I turn network offline, it doesn't work.

I think it's a scope issue, but I don't know how I can make it work.

My first script is in the index.html, my sw.js is in the folder /theme/website_mobile/sw.js and my website loads some resources from multiple places on the server.

Is there any way to make it work without moving my sw.js?

Comment: Because, like I said, the website have js files, css files and images files in multiple directories in the server. I do not have any errors, the sw.js installs and activated well, but it's like it doesn't fetch any request when I turn down the network.

Comment: Sorry, different meaning of the word "scope." :-)

Comment: Oh ! Yeah of course, you're right! Maybe 'scope' is not the better term.

Comment: This is your serviceworker scope '/theme/website_mobile/' You should get some files back from your cache since some requests that are cached are in scope. Why not add some more logging to see what is returned and what is fetched from the network?

Comment: Arno > I just remove the scope option in the register() method, but it didn't work. 
What logs would you want me to add?

Comment: The only log I have in the console is : Service worker active. Nothing else, in the Application panel, I have my sw.js activated and running.

Comment: Here is my sources panel : http://hpics.li/74b8aec

Comment: A service worker is active for the directory where it is registered, so if you want it on your website, then it should be in the root directory

Comment: Icepickle > Yep, if I move my sw.js to the directory folder, it works, but I want to know if this kind case is possible. I'm afraid that it's not... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @HassanMangepasdepain Indeed it is not possible, the max scope is the place from where the serviceworker is loaded from. But this all has to do with being able to control what you like to cache, so this is essentially a good thing :)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

NO, i guess not. 
The scope defines what your SW can cache but also where it get's active!

> A single service worker can control many pages. Each time a page
>   within your scope is loaded, the service worker is installed against
>   that page and operates on it.

from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Registering_your_worker)

so your service will get active on pages below *https://yourdoma.in/theme/website_mobile/*